# How do I recover Windows 10 with files recovered from a drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery

*Originally posted on ServerFault - told that was the wrong place, pointed here*

I had a drive failure about 2 months ago on my custom built PC with Windows 10 (probably professional version). It was a Seagate drive and they sent the drive to recovery and sent back a USB slimdrive with all of the files recovered.

My question is: How do I now recover back to Windows 10?

I was hoping I could copy those files onto a new drive and boot up Windows, but that results in "No MBR Found". I also tried booting from the USB slimdrive, but that results in a different message telling me to select a proper boot device.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't simply copy files over to a drive and have it boot. You will need to install a fresh copy of windows onto your new drive, then manually copy over the files from the recovered drive that you need.

Comment: "How do I now recover back to Windows 10?" - You don't;  They only recovered your personal files.  The HDD you describe doesn't contain a boot partition

Comment: In the future, keep a **disk image**, which contains *all* the system files, the boot sectors, and your *personal* files, as well. There are numerous free and commercial applications to do this, such as Macrium Reflect Free and DriveImage XML.

Answer (score 0):

The recovery service only recovered your files. Hopefully you only had one partition
on the disk, so they didn't mix up everything, and hopefully they recovered the
folders structure and with all the right permissions.

A way to make it work might be:

- Use the Windows 10 boot media to install Windows 10 on the disk from scratch
- Boot from the boot media into the Command Prompt
- Find the disk label on the internal disk of Windows 10 (may be `D:`)
- Find the disk label of the backup disk (perhaps `E:`)
- Copy everything from the backup disk to the internal disk
- Reboot from the internal disk (and cross your fingers).

If this does not work, contact the disk recovery service and complain.
They might have more advice, or might be inclined to repeat the recovery
while doing a better effort.

If they refuse, you will have to repeat the installation of Windows 10, install
your applications, then recover your data files manually and selectively.

Answer (score 0):

Hard drives and modestly size SSD are cheap.

I would get a samsung 256/512 (250/500)gb ssd and reload windows.

You can reload windows from microsoft using the media creation tool.

Your windows license is tied to a microsoft account, and the rest of the hardware which you still have.  So you should be able to login to your microsoft account or if that fails you might have to call microsoft and read off the string and get an activation number over the phone.  Once windows is registered/licensed you can switch back to a local account if you want.

It would be incredible hard to rebuild windows from recovered files.

Sometimes it is better to do a fresh install and start over.

**Here is some food for thought if you have spare time, and your willing to deal with a lot of extra work.**

The majority of windows settings are in the windows registry located here c:\windows\system32\config and in some hidden files in the root of your user profile.

Once you had a working copy of windows you could backup the existing files, and then boot from a windows install CD/DVD/USB media.

Then you could overwrite all the files in the config folder and the hidden files in your user profile.  Now after you reboot "Here be the dragons", windows will like complain about missing files, and have issues regarding those missing files.  Resolving these issues one at a time will be a real pain and a time sink.

You will still need to hope the files from program files and program files(x86) and c:\programdata\ are present and intact from the recovery service or your old hard drive.  The appdata folder from your user profile is another area you will need.

In the end you will probably still need to re-install most of your programs.

While in theory it could be done, once you realize how much time and effort is involved most people give up.  Even then you could be left with a significant number of errors to resolve.